# Return all rows irrespective updated or not, in update query of inner selected resords

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

When I use the following query, I got only updated rows using "returning" keyword:

```
Update lprs_db.chaallan_details
set locking_initial_time=now(),
    lockid = '101'
where ((lockid = '101' and now() - locking_initial_time <= Interval '1 hour')
       OR (lockid = '' or now()-locking_initial_time > Interval '1 hour'))
and transid in (select transid
                from lprs_db.chaallan_details
                order by event_time DESC
                OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10) returning *;
```

I can do UPDATE on SELECTED records to avoid a race condition, but to display I want all records after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.  All records specified in the WHERE clause of the update get updated.  It seems like you want one part of the WHERE to specify what gets returned, and a different part of the WHERE clause to specify which subset of those get updated. I assume the "transid in ..." is the first of those, and everything else is the second?

One method is to update all the rows you want returned, setting some of them to the same value they already have.  This is annoying, as you may need one CASE statement for each column you are updating.  You could try to do something simple with a CTE, but in that case I think it might be hard to control whether the returned value is the new one or the old one. Or you could do a CTE then have a UNION ALL, one of which returns via the RETURNING clause, and the other which returns directly.

```
with t as (select transid from lprs_db.chaallan_details order by event_time DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10),
 u as (update lprs_db.chaallan_details ... where update_criteria and transid in (select * from t)
select * from u 
union all 
select * from lprs_db.chaallan_details where not (update_criteria) and and transid in (select * from t)
```